# ASP.NET Identity setup and Entity Framework data base first approach

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am started looking at ASP.NET Identity Framework. It is powered with Entity Framework 6.

It is using the default database with the number of related tables.
`AspNetUsers`, `AspnetUserRoles`, `AspnetUserLogins`, `AspnetUserClaims`, `AspnetRoles`, `_MigrationHistory`

Currently looking in to solution to decrease the number of tables by following that [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/12/12/a-simple-implementation-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity.aspx) and [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)

After that i need to add my business tables `Products`, `Categories`, etc...

So here is my question.

Currently looks like using `Code First` i can handle `User Profiles`.
But what next, if i need to add a new Business Tables to database do I need to create `edmx` model and keep all entities there including Aspnet Identity Enitnites?

Is there any way to do that(to switch `ASP.NET Identity Framework` to use entities defined in custom `edmx`file)?

Or may be I have to keep `ASP.NET Identity Framework`/`User Profiles` like it is and handle my business tables through custom `edmx` model?

What can you suggest?

I think it is good idea to handle everything through `edmx` file so I can made any changes directly in database and then update `edmx` file and regenerate the Enitites and Datacontext using `tt` template.

Comment: Seems all EF work has been on Code First and Model/Database First have been abandoned. You should be able to all all three in the same project interchangeably at any time. Update the class updates the model and vice versa. And import database items as well.